# Host redmine to docker redmine ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, compiler-errors, redmine, redmine-api, econnreset

I need a help from you. my task is dockerized my current redmine.
almost 2 week I am working on this task.
I copied public folder from host redmine to docker container redmine/public
I copied all plugins and installed successfully 
but problem is image,my theme background image, wiki image is not disply.

I think my docker redmine is not find path to image.

any one know how to display image?

I will explain what step i do so far.

```
docker network create --driver bridge redmine_network
docker volume create postgres-data
docker volume create redmine-data

docker container run -d                         \ 
      --name postgres                           \ 
      --network redmine_network                 \ 
      -v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \ 
      --restart always                          \ 
      -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD='password'             \ 
      -e POSTGRES_DB='redmine'                  \ 
      postgres:latest



docker container run -d                         \ 
    --name redmine                              \ 
    --network redmine_network                   \ 
    -p 80:3000                                  \ 
    --restart always                            \ 
    -v redmine-data:/usr/src/redmine/files      \ 
    -e REDMINE_DB_POSTGRES='postgres'           \ 
    -e REDMINE_DB_DATABASE='redmine'            \ 
    -e REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD='password'           \ 
    redmine:latest
```

inside the container i install some package and gem for my plugins

```
docker exec -it redmine bash

apt update 
apt install build-essential libpq-dev pkg-config libmagickwand-dev ruby ruby-dev
bundle install --no-deployment
gem install will_paginate 
gem install jenkins_api_client
gem install activesupport -v 4.2.8
gem install  haml-rails -v 1.0
gem install deface -v 1.0.2
gem install brakeman -v 4.8.0
bundle updates
```

docker redmine log file

```
Resolving dependencies...
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
[2020-03-17 16:31:41] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2020-03-17 16:31:41] INFO  ruby 2.4.4 (2018-03-28) [x86_64-linux]
[2020-03-17 16:31:41] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=3000
[2020-03-17 16:32:03] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:16 
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:308:in `block in start_thread'
[2020-03-17 16:32:03] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:14 
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:308:in `block in start_thread'
[2020-03-17 16:32:08] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:19 
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:308:in `block in start_thread'
[2020-03-17 16:32:08] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:13 
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:308:in `block in start_thread'
[2020-03-17 16:32:08] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:18 
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:308:in `block in start_thread'
[2020-03-17 16:32:09] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:16 
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:308:in `block in start_thread'
[2020-03-17 16:32:09] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:14 
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:308:in `block in start_thread'
```

anyone could explain how to clear this error.. please

Answer (score 0):

I want to make docker redmine same like my host redmine.
i can explain what i did so far.

create docker containers for redmine 3.4.4 and postgresql:latest with network and volume for each container
https://medium.com/@gurayy/setting-up-redmine-with-docker-be110387ba1c

install package and gem in redmine container

copy /public folder to docker redmine:/usr/src/redmine

copy all plugins to docker redmine:/usr/src/redmine/plugins

install plugins
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=readme_at_repositories RAILS_ENV=production

docker container restart redmine

check everything work fine

make a pg_dump from my host machine

```
/usr/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -W -F -T --file=/tmp/redminedata.sqlc projectportal
```

enter to my postgresql container and restore my database

```
pg_restore -c -U postgres -h postgres -d projectportal /tmp/redminedata.sqlc
```

restart redmine container and I check again redmine in browser

when I check my redmine .png and .jpg files not working (not showing)
all data are migrated but image are missing and my theme background image .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvI1g.png)